# Cant able to see content on google map baloon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

```
twistSection(document.getElementById('page:form:resultsBlock:debugSection').childNodes[0].childNodes[0]); // initially hide the debug section

var contacts = {
    !contactsJson
}; // Array of contact data, some of them might have lat/long info, some we'll have to geocode client side
var coords = []; // Just the latitude/longitude for each contact
var requestCounter = 0;

var markers = []; // Red things we pin to the map.
var balloon = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // Comic-like baloon that floats over markers.

function geocodeClientSide() {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].Location__Latitude__s != null && contacts[i].Location__Longitude__s != null) {
            coords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(contacts[i].Location__Latitude__s, contacts[i].Location__Longitude__s));
        } else {
            ++requestCounter;
            var address = contacts[i].MailingStreet + ' ' + contacts[i].MailingCity + ' ' + contacts[i].MailingCountry;
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            if (geocoder) {
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'address': address
                }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        coords.push(results[0].geometry.location);
                    } else {
                        var pTag = document.createElement("p");
                        pTag.innerHTML = status;
                        document.getElementById('log').appendChild(pTag);
                    }
                    if (--requestCounter == 0) {
                        drawMap();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    // It could be the case that all was geocoded on server side (or simply retrieved from database).
    // So if we're lucky - just proceed to drawing the map.
    if (requestCounter == 0) {
        drawMap();
    }
}

function drawMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: coords[0],
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; ++i) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: coords[i],
            title: contacts[i].Name,
            zIndex: i
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            var index = this.zIndex;
            balloon.content = '<b>' + contacts[index].Name + '</b><br/>' + contacts[index].Account.Name + '<br/>' + contacts[index].Email;
            balloon.open(map, marker, content);
        });

        markers.push(marker);
    }
}
geocodeClientSide();
```

I am plotting list of contacts address from salesforce .it is plotting the balloon on the map correctly but it is not showing any content .

I am try many possible ways but i dont see content on the balloon Can any body tell me where the issue coming from ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question (instead of balloon put infowindow this is the appropriate word for the balloon). Put your code in a fiddle as well.

Comment: @MrUpsidown balloon=infowindow, look at the functions of the balloon...

Comment: I know it's an InfoWindow... that's just a way to let OP know this is unclear.

Comment: @MrUpsidown  I have edited my question let me know your doubts

Comment: @eugensunic it is already infowindow intiated at top

Comment: When i kept alert for alert(balloon.content) it is showing alert with data

Comment: balloon.open(map, marker); did you try only this?

Comment: yes is any other function is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some information: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure

You need to use a closure when attaching events in a loop. Here is an example:

```
var locations = [
    [new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0), 'Marker 1', 'Infowindow content for Marker 1'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(0, 1), 'Marker 2', 'Infowindow content for Marker 2'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(0, 2), 'Marker 3', 'Infowindow content for Marker 3'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(1, 0), 'Marker 4', 'Infowindow content for Marker 4'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(1, 1), 'Marker 5', 'Infowindow content for Marker 5'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(1, 2), 'Marker 6', 'Infowindow content for Marker 6']
];

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: locations[i][0],
        map: map,
        title: locations[i][1]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {

        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][2]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }

    })(marker, i));
}
```

Notice the differences with your code. Instead of using `function() { ... }` in your event listener use `(function(marker, i) { ... })(marker, i)`

Below is a working demo of how to use a single InfoWindow object with multiple markers.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/peor6rqk/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Replace your for loop from function `drawMap()` with the following code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; ++i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: coords[i],
        title: contacts[i].Name,
        zIndex: i
    });

var balloon = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        var index = this.zIndex;
    balloon.setContent(contacts[index].Name + contacts[index].Account.Name + contacts[index].Email);
        balloon.open(map, marker);
    });

    markers.push(marker);
}
```